# How to get --color output when using webpack-dev-middleware?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-middleware

I have an `express` API I'm using in my app so I am using `webpack-dev-middleware` and `webpack-hot-middleware`.

I'm trying to figure out how to get the `webpack --color` option when I use `webpack` through the API.

This is what I have right now:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const webpackConfig = require('../../webpack.config')
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig)

const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  noInfo: true
})
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler)

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware)
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware)
```

I am currently using `webpack@2.2.0-rc.3`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, add

```
stats: {
  colors: true
}
```

to your options, like:

```
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  stats: {
    colors: true
  }
})
```

Check out the [usage section](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#usage).

Tested with webpack 2.2.1 and webpack-dev-middleware 1.10.1.